# Why aren't reputation points the same for Super User and Super User Meta?

Tags: support, reputation

Why aren't reputation points the same for Super User and Super User Meta?

What is the reason for this difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a normal browser/site caching issue.  Just give Meta some time to catch up with the main site and your problem will be gone.